# Java Object creation per request

Tags: java

I have a service which gets multiple requests at a time. It has 20 threads and process requests in parallel. My requirement is I have to pass 2 fields from the input request to all the other classes in the flow. These 2 fields will never be modified. I understand that I can pass it to each class either as an object or as individual fields. But I dont want to do that as I'm using these fields to just emit metrics and I dont want to pollute all classes with these fields.

Is there any way to create an object and use it across all classes unique to a request.

Comment: If the requests run a thread you can make an implementation of runnable with an static field, containing your object. That way every instance of the thread will be able to access that object.

Comment: So you want to set them once, through a request and then never change them again and reuse the data in other classes?

Comment: When OP said "will never be modified", I'm assuming that he meant "during the execution of the flow". If not, then these fields should not come from an input request at all.

@MiguelLuna: the fields come from individual requests. By storing them in static fields you get a serious thread-safety issue. One request can overwrite the values for another request. A `ThreadLocal` could help, as long as no asynchronous processing is done, as that would be executed in a different thread and therefore not have access to the values stored for the current request.